# Replace command in powershell is deleting the whole content

Tags: powershell

I am new to powershell. I create a powershell script which need to search a string in the path provided in parameters and replace that string. But actually it is replacing entire file content with new string.

I am using Powershell in Windows 10 OS.
Code:

```
param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ParameterSetName="Path", Position=0,HelpMessage='Data folder Path')]
        [string] $Path,


        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, HelpMessage='Input the string to be replaced')]
        [string] $Input,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,HelpMessage='Input the new string that need to be replaced')]
        [string] $Replace

)

$a = Test-Path $Path
IF ($a -eq $True) {Write-Host "Path Exists"} ELSE {Write-Host "Path Doesnot exits"}
$configFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -include *.pro, *.rux -recurse
$Append = join-path -path $path \*
$b = test-path $Append -include *.pro, *.rux
If($b -eq $True) {
  foreach ($file in $configFiles)
  {
    (Get-Content $file.PSPath) |
    Foreach-Object { $_ -replace [regex]::Escape($Input), $Replace } |
    Set-Content $file.PSPath
  } 
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell
$wshell.Popup("Operation Completed",0,"Done",0x0)
}
```

Comment: `$input` is an automatic variable, use a different variable name.

Comment: Thanks BenH. It works :)

Answer (score 1):

As best I can read this without directly reproducing it, this is where it goes wrong:

(get-content $file.pspath) gets the entire content of the file, not its name.

Your "foreach" then regexes every line *in* the file, and finally "set-content" replaces the contents of the file, not its path.

If you want to change the name of a file, you are looking for Rename-Item, not Set-Content. If you want the name of a file $file.Name will do, you don't need Get-Content, which will ... get its content :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply....but i want to change the content which are in the files like version update etc given in a particular location. For example if the existing file contains string like " This is string" then i want to replace this string with "This is a string". Also when i tried replacing without parameter it is replacing correctly. When i use parameter only i am facing the issue.

Comment: Ah ok. I misunderstood your case then. I thought you only wanted to replace things in the filename. Your should probably look at the comment from @BenH to your question and not use the $Input variable.

Answer (score 1):

This should be a working solution.

```
Param(
  [Parameter(Mandatory,
             ParameterSetName='Path',
             Position=0,
             HelpMessage='Data folder Path')]
  [String]
  $Path,
  [Parameter(Mandatory,
             HelpMessage='Input the string to be replaced')]
  [String]
  $StringToReplace,
  [Parameter(Mandatory,
             HelpMessage='Input the new string that need to be replaced')]
  [String]
  $ReplacementString
)
If (!(Test-Path $Path)) {
  Write-Host 'Path does not exist'
  Return
}

Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Include *.pro,*.rux -Recurse |
  ? { $_.Name -like "*$StringToReplace*" } |
  % { Rename-Item $_ $($ReplacementString+$_.Extension) }

(New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell).Popup("Operation Completed",0,"Done",0x0)
```